# I am pretty confuse how to do this

Tags: logarithms

> Find $\log_8 27$ when $\log_2 3  = a$.

What is the solution?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: The latter equation really means
$$
\log_2 3 = a \qquad \Leftrightarrow \qquad 3 = 2^a
$$
Do the same logic for the other equation. Can you relate the two equations somehow? Hint: $27=3^3$.

Comment: Well, you got this $a$ given. What do $2$ and $27$ have to do with the numbers $8$ and $27$? Can you use the connection somehow? What does $log_2(3) = a$ even mean, how is it defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\log_{2}3 = a$ means that $2^a = 3$. By cubing both sides we get

$(2^a)^3 = 3^3$

$\Rightarrow (2^3)^a = 3^3$

$\Rightarrow 8^a = 27$

$\Rightarrow \log_{8}27 = a$

Comment: But do I have to find the value of log27 base 8?

Comment: It is the same value is $\log_2{3}$, so just calling it $a$ is all you need to do to identify it.

Comment: I guess that depends on how the question is worded. You are given that $log_{2}3 =a$, and $log_{8}27 = a$ also. The value of $log_{8}27$ is just some long decimal number, but leaving it as that is its exact form. I imagine the question just wants you to put "a" as the answer.